# How to enable google map navigation in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-urls

I have two points on google map first one is the source and second is the destination, I have the route between these points on the map.Now I want to navigate user from source to destination as Google does on Google Map Like this:-[image]

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 12):

The Google Maps Android API v2 doesn't provide any functionality for navigation. It is in contradiction with Terms of Service of Maps APIs. Have a look at section 10.4 c (iii) of ToS:

> **No navigation.** You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4

If you need navigation you should create an [intent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents) that opens the Google Maps app in navigation mode. There is a Google Maps URLs that allows to construct a universal, cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps intents from your application. You can open navigation mode of native app following this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer but if that's the case, how does uber and ola show in-app navigation?

Comment: They use Navigation SDK that requires separate license and I suspect it's expensive. This SDK was mentioned in I/0 2018: https://youtu.be/XVjyIA3f_Ic?t=21m8s

Comment: @Andromeda Any progress?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to stimulate a view like that but not embedded like uber but very close.

```
 public void loadNavigationView(String lat,String lng){
    Uri navigation = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+lat+","+lng+"");
    Intent navigationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, navigation);
    navigationIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(navigationIntent);
}
```

You call the method and provide the latitude and longitude.It will launch Google map navigation.Like uber

Comment: Hello, where is this documented? I would like to add several stops

Answer (score 1):

After searching, I found something on this context. Now google providing In-app Navigation and Google Maps turn-by-turn directions support. It's paid, you can check more about this on below link.

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/rides-and-deliveries

Not sure if it solve your problem or not.