# how to show icon to switching driver application from google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing cab booking application for driver,is there any way to show app redirecting icon on  google map and on click of icon driver app should be open.here i attached screenshot.Please suggest me if possible solution.[image]

Comment: Have a look at [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action). You can add a button that opens the native Maps app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable google map navigation in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734051/how-to-enable-google-map-navigation-in-android-app)

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461979/how-to-overlay-views-in-other-apps